# Open browser security info with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, https

When I'm on https, the browser shows a secure icon in the address bar. I can usually (depending on browser) click on this to see more info in a native popup.

See chromes implementation here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w62tc6oaj63knp/Screenshot%202015-12-30%2014.01.53.png?dl=0

Other browsers implement equivalent features.

I want to draw attention to the security of my site, by showing a picture of this icon by my "Buy" CTA, and something that says "Check for this secure icon in your browser". I want the more info section (as in the screenshot) to expand when my icon is clicked.

Is this possible?

Apologies if question has already been answered, I tried to search but not sure if this info box has a name, so not sure what to search for.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I don't think this would be possible.  The best you would be able to do is to create a similar-looking popup that would be place underneath the security icon/address bar.  You can also detect if it's coming from HTTPS or not... Allowing you to determine whether or not you actually want to show it.  Etc.

Answer (score 11):

No it's not possible, sorry.

Browsers let Javascript to interact with their core to certain level, but that's about it. `window` object provides many functions to interact with browser but opening "Site's Info popup" is not provided.

You can read about Mozilla and Chrome extensions and see they interact with the browser through JavaScript, but this is only inside extensions, signed scripts and scripts located on user's hard drives.

So if your application needs access to something the browser should ask the user its self or you could instruct the user on how to do this.

I Hope it helps. :(